# XDocument object serialization to JSON issue using Jil in c# (stackoverflow exception)

Tags: c#, json, json.net, xml-serialization, jil

I have an XDocument object that comes from business layer, it includes a document property which repeats itself infinitely (God knows why!) with the same values in every repeat and it becomes problematic when I want to serialize this object to JSON using Jil.

Since the document property repeats itself infinitely I get Stackoverflow exception when trying to serialize the object using `Serialize` method of Jil.

Here is my serialization code (it's part of method that gets an object as input (Data) and do serialization on it then return stringed JSON):

```
 JSON.Serialize(Data, output,Options.IncludeInherited);
```

Is there any way that I can prevent my XDocument object from being repeated infinitely?

Or I serialize my object to JSON using Jil without getting Stackoverflow  exception?

Newtonsoft has a separate method for XML serialization:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlNode);
```

but I couldn't find its equivalent in Jil.